# How does a PC determine which network adapter to use when given an IP/DNS to connect to?

Tags: networking, tcpip

I have so many network adapters on my PC. If I type for example "Ping 192.168.191.128", how does my PC now which network adapter to use?

What if it's a DNS name like "mylocal.ddd.com", how does my PC now which adapter configured DNS server to look for?

Answer (score 1):

All IP devices have a routing table which tells what interface to use to transmit a packet.  When the PC has a packet to send, it looks up the destination in the routing table and finds the best (longest) match.  It's very common to have a default route (also called a default gateway) that matches any destination.

On a windows PC, you can see the routing table by typing `route print`.